# Cost efficiently pair each line with lines of another file

Tags: text-processing

I have a very huge file (~10Gb data) which contains data in below format -

```
'1','1'    
'2','2'    
'3','3'    
'4','4'    
'5','5'    
'6','6'    
'7','7'    
'8','8'    
'9','9'    
'10','10'
```

and format of another file (which is 300Kb in size) is -

```
1,2    
1,3    
1,4    
1,5    
1,6    
1,7    
1,8    
1,9    
1,10    
2,1    
2,3    
2,4   
2,5    
2,6    
2,7    
2,8    
2,9
```

desired output -

```
'1','1','1,2',    
'2','2','1,3',    
'3','3','1,4',    
'4','4','1,5',    
'5','5','1,6',    
'6','6','1,7',    
'7','7','1,8',    
'8','8','1,9',    
'9','9','1,10',    
'10','10','2,1',
```

since the input file contains more than 10 million records. so doing it via a loop will be a very costly operation.

Comment: `paste -d",''" 1 - 2 - - </dev/null`

Comment: paste will work if number of lines in both of the files are same.
This is not the case here. The larger file has 1Billions rows while the smaller one has only 90 rows.
Every lines in the larger file should have a value from smaller file.

Comment: What criteria select the matches? How many lines are in each of the files (a solution valid if both have a thousand lines isn't necessarily useful if they have millions of lines, and if one has millions and the other one a few dozen will suggest yet another approach)? Are the files sorted (or does the order matter), for input and output? What tools are available (i.e., can write a specific C program, has to be done in shell, a scripting language like Python or Perl is acceptable, ...)?

Comment: I don't understand how the lines are matched. You seem to match line N of file 1 with line N of file 2, but what happens when you go beyond the end of the shortest file?

Answer (score 0):

Done this via below -

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[i++]=$0; max=i; next} 
{if ((NR % max) == 0) {i=max-1} else {i=(NR%max) - 1}; 
printf "%s,%s\n",$0,a[i]}' smaller_file larger_file
```

But if someone knows the faster way than this, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d",''," ./file1 - ./file2 - - </dev/null >out
```

...given your example data that writes to output:

```
'1','1','1,2',
'2','2','1,3',
'3','3','1,4',
'4','4','1,5',
'5','5','1,6',
'6','6','1,7',
'7','7','1,8',
'8','8','1,9',
'9','9','1,10',
'10','10','2,1',
,'2,3',
,'2,4',
,'2,5',
,'2,6',
,'2,7',
,'2,8',
,'2,9',
,'',
```

---

It's a little difficult for me to tell exactly what the criteria are for stopping the output, but to write output identical to your example output:

```
{   paste -d",''," ./file1 - ./file2 - - |
    sed -ne's/,/&/4p;t' -eq
}   </dev/null
```

---

```
'1','1','1,2',
'2','2','1,3',
'3','3','1,4',
'4','4','1,5',
'5','5','1,6',
'6','6','1,7',
'7','7','1,8',
'8','8','1,9',
'9','9','1,10',
'10','10','2,1',
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're looking to cycle through the contents of the smaller file

With `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[++i]=$0; next}; 
 {print $0, a[FNR % i? FNR % i: i]}' smaller_file larger_file
```

And `python`

```
from itertools import cycle, izip
with open('larger_file') as f1, open('smaller_file') as f2:
    z = izip(f1, cycle(f2))
    for l, m in z:
           print l.rstrip('\n'), m.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have already pointed out, [paste](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) is the right tool here.

```
paste -d ,\'\' file1 /dev/null file2 /dev/null
```

If `file2` is shorter than `file1`, then `paste` will act as if it had as many empty lines at the end to match `file2`.

If you want to act as if `file2` repeated over and over, make it repeat over and over until you reach the line count of `file1`.

```
while true; do cat file2; done | head -n "$(wc -l file1)" |
paste -d ,\'\' file1 /dev/null - /dev/null
```

This requires going over `file1` twice. Depending on the relative speed of your CPU and I/O, it may be faster to eschew `paste` and instead use a tool that can process multiple files in a more flexible way, such as awk. Here's an awk solution that doesn't require loading either file in memory entirely (if `file2` is small, the disk cache will take care of this anyway).

```
awk -v file2=file2 '
    !getline s <file2 {close(file2); getline s <file2}
    {print $0 ",\047" s "\047"}' file1
```

Explanation: `getline s <file2` reads the next line from `file2`, opening it if necessary. If this fails (because the end of the file has been reached), close the file and start again.